# Multiple Columns for HUE parameter in Seaborn violinplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am working with tips data set, and here is the head of data set.

```
 total_bill tip     sex    smoker day time  size
0   16.99   1.01    Female  No  Sun Dinner  2
1   10.34   1.66    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
2   21.01   3.50    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
3   23.68   3.31    Male    No  Sun Dinner  2
4   24.59   3.61    Female  No  Sun Dinner  4
```

My code is

```py
sns.violinplot(x='day',y='total_bill',data=tips, hue=['sex','smoker'])
```

I want a violinplot of day with total_bill in which hue is sex and smoker, but I can not find any option to set multiple values of `hue`. Is there any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `seaborn.catplot` in order to use `'sex'` as `hue` and `'smoker'` as column for generating two side by side violinplot.
Check this code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set()

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.catplot(x = "day",
            y = "total_bill",
            hue = "sex",
            col = "smoker",
            data = tips,
            kind = "violin",
            split = True)

plt.show()
```

which gives me this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 24):

The faceting approach suggested by [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62230987) is probably nicer in this case, but might not be easily applicable to other kinds of Seaborn plots (e.g. in my case, `ecdfplot`). So I just wanted to share that I figured out a solution which does what OP originally asked, i.e. actually use multiple columns for the `hue` parameter.

The trick is that hue can either be a column name, or a sequence of the same length as your data, listing the color categories to assign each data point to. So...

```
sns.violinplot(x='day', y='total_bill', data=tips, hue='sex')
```

... is basically the same as:

```
sns.violinplot(x='day', y='total_bill', data=tips, hue=tips['sex'])
```

You typically wouldn't use the latter, it's just more typing to achieve the same thing -- unless you want to construct a custom sequence on the fly:

```
sns.violinplot(x='day', y='total_bill', data=tips,
               hue=tips[['sex', 'smoker']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
```

[image: Violin plot using two columns for hue parameter]

The way you build the sequence that you pass via `hue` is entirely up to you, the only requirement is that it must have the same length as your data, and if an array-like, it must be one-dimensional, so you can't just pass `hue=tips[['sex', 'smoker']]`, you have to somehow concatenate the columns into one. I chose `tuple` as the most versatile way, but if you want to have more control over the formatting, build a `Series` of strings (saving it into a separate variable here for better readability, but you don't have to):

```
hue = tips['sex'].astype(str) + ', ' + tips['smoker'].astype(str)
sns.violinplot(x='day', y='total_bill', data=tips, hue=hue)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- An option, that creates a new column, similar to the answer from [dlukes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1826241/dlukes).
- Create a column of combined strings from either `'day'`/`'sex'` or `'day'`/`'smoker'`, set that as `x=`, use `'smoker'` or `'sex'`, respectively, as `hue=`, and set `split=True`.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# load sample data
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# create a new column
tips['Day - Sex'] = tips.day.astype(str) + ' - ' + tips.sex.astype(str)

# set to categorical to specify an order
categories = ['Thur - Female', 'Thur - Male', 'Fri - Female', 'Fri - Male', 'Sat - Female', 'Sat - Male', 'Sun - Female', 'Sun - Male']
tips['Day - Sex'] = pd.Categorical(tips['Day - Sex'], categories=categories, ordered=True)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.violinplot(x='Day - Sex', y='total_bill', data=tips, hue='smoker', ax=ax, split=True)
```

[image]